# How to make same size div for diff size image and title length in bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5

I am working on an angular project where I am getting the data in image and title and location. I tried to make a responsive div but unable to make them in one size.

```
      <div *ngFor="let company of companies" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body py-0 text-center">
              <input [checked]="true"   type="radio" formControlName="scope" (click)="nextFormPostion(nextFormPostionName)"  (change)="nextFormPostion(nextFormPostionName)"  id="img{{company.scope}}" class="d-none imgbgchk" value="{{company.scope}}">
              <label  for="img{{company.scope}}">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-12" style="height: 6rem ; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <img  src="{{company.logo}}"  class="mt-1 img-fluid mh-100" alt="Image 1">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 mt-2" style="min-height: 3rem;font-size: 12px;text-transform: none;">
                    <span>{{company.company}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 mt-1" style="min-height: 2.5rem;font-size: 12px;text-transform: none;">
                    <span>{{company.country}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tick_container">
                  <div class="tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

company.logo is the image path and company.company is the name of the company. I want to make image in vertical and horizontal align center and if company name length is new line it change the size of all divs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bootstrap exactly to do that you can use JavaScript to get the div side you want and apply as width + height.

Also you can use CSS with, for example:

```
width: 100%
```

Comment: width 100% not working if i am using display black then vertical algin is not working

Comment: So use JavaScript to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to check if you have any border, margin, padding that is affecting your code. I don't know, I don't have enough information. But I believe it could be because Bootstrap puts automatic padding on .row

For this you can put

```
<div class="row g-0">
</div>
```

[Bootstrap 5 - No gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#no-gutters)

Or if it is in another element, simply add the px-0 class that removes the padding from the widths.